# Oracle SQL Developer ER Diagrammer number datatype not available

Tags: oracle, entity-relationship, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm creating a relational model and I need to set a column's datatype to `NUMBER(19)`.  I can's find this option in the column properties.  Specifically, the drop down next to logical type doesn't contain `NUMBER`.  Is it set somewhere else?

Comment: What version of SQL Developer are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 3.2